# -S unknown option when using sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server-2008, sqlcmd

I get an error when I execute the command below from a DOS window in Windows XP with SQL Server 2008. -S is the option to specify the server name.

error: Sqlcmd: '-S': unknown option.

sqlcmd –S localhost –d databasename -i C:\files\somefile.sql –E

Comment: Do you actually say "localhost"? Do you put in the server name, or the SQL server instance name?

Comment: Try to type 'sqlcmd /?'. What it returns? Maybe you have another program in your PATH which has the same name.

Comment: @Philip - It gives other error message when the host name is incorrect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's working now using '.' as the server name when I typed the line manually.
What I did earlier was type the command in an editor, copied the ine and pasted into the command line. My guess is that an invisible control character got in there during the copy. I opened another dos window and typed a similar command using 'localhost' and it worked. I never used sqlcmd to connect to a server so I thought my syntax was wrong.

localhost, . & (local) should all work and if you use a non existent server name it will complain that it couldn't connect. It shouldn't say -S is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Is localhost the correct reference to use? Try sqlcmd -L to get the list of servers.

Answer (score 0):

`LocalHost` is for IIS

`(LOCAL)` is for SQL Server.  Or you can use a period

Comment: localhost is a Windows alias. You can ping localhost and you can connect to localhost using SSMS. So no it's not for IIS only